# AsyncTask #1 :An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: java, android

I am developing app with Jsoup. The problem is it is not working when I am calling it from other class with the help of Getters. But it is running when I call it within Single Activity. I am not able to find why exactly it is not working, as it should. 
Here are the logCat files with all the activities.

**LogCat**

```
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:57)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:27)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.example.frgbdf.jsoupAct$Parsee.doInBackground(jsoupAct.java:30)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at com.example.frgbdf.jsoupAct$Parsee.doInBackground(jsoupAct.java:1)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-14 20:16:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1871):     ... 4 more
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LineGraph.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

**LineGraph**

```
public class LineGraph extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        jsoupAct mJsoupAct = new jsoupAct();
        String parseStrings;
        parseStrings = mJsoupAct.getOutput();
        Log.d("xstring", parseStrings + "");
    }
}
```

**jsoupAct**

```
public class jsoupAct extends Activity {
    String output = "00";
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        url = "www.google.com";
    }

    public void mExecute() {
        new Parsee().execute();

    }

    public class Parsee extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                String body = doc.body().text();
                output = body.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return output;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(output);
        }

    }

    public String getOutput() {
        mExecute();
        return output;
    }

    public void setOutput(String output) {
        this.output = output;
    }
}
```

Comment: mb   url with "http" not "www" ?

Comment: try using `http://www.google.com` add the http part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are specifying the `URL` in a string **local** to the `jsoupAct activity`. The string will be null if you try to access from other Activities. To solve it move the string **inside the AsyncTask** class and it will work

Or add empty constructor to the `jsonAct` activity and assign the value of `url` in it. `onCreate()` is called only when to start an activity using the `startActivity()`

Answer (score 2):

You have already answered your own question:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must supply a valid URL
    at org.jsoup.helper.Validate.notEmpty(Validate.java:102)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.url(HttpConnection.java:57)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:27)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.connect(Jsoup.java:73)
    at com.example.frgbdf.jsoupAct$Parsee.doInBackground(jsoupAct.java:30)
    at com.example.frgbdf.jsoupAct$Parsee.doInBackground(jsoupAct.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    ... 4 more
```

Comment: Reposting logcat is in no way an answer. The OP obviously doesn't know *why* the error is occurring or how to fix it.